# Require a method to identify deflationary tokens before initiating a transaction

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, blockchains, block-explorer

I have a quick question regarding identifying deflationary tokens before initiating a crypto transaction.

For instance, I recently intended to exchange 20 ABC tokens for 10 DANK tokens(Which sends 0.1% to token.burn), while doing the transaction do I have any way to get this information? I can use SDK if required on any other solution.